# Loop through array in react onclick using Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, onclick, react-hooks

I have an array of objects that I load from a `json` file and I want each item to load separately when I click a button. I completed that but the main problem is when the index goes out of bounds so then it shows

> TypeError "Cannot read property 'content' of undefined".

How can I make then index be `0` again when the index reaches the last item? I tried solving it by including some if statements inside the button but no luck.
Here is the related part of the code till now:

```
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const questions_size = Data.length;
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const current = Data[num].content;

  (...)
  return (
    <Container>
      <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
        About
      </Typography>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={()=> num<questions_size?setNum(num+1): setNum(0)}>Επομενο</Button>
      <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardContent>

          <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
            <p style={{ fontFamily: 'Tangerine, serif', fontSize: '35px', textShadow: '4px 4px 4px #aaa'}}>{current}</p>
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  )
```

Comment: would you show the `Data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your current approach is that the highest valid index is `questions_size - 1`, it should work like this:

```
onClick={() => num < questions_size - 1 ? setNum(num + 1) : setNum(0)}
```

Another option is to use the remainder operator:

```
onClick={() => setNum(num + 1 % questions_size)}
```

Answer (score 1):

this code will only run when the data changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (num > Data.length) {
    setNum(0)
  }
},[Data])
```